# iOS 7 CSS padding has no background-color

Tags: html, ios, css

Is anyone else having an issue with the Safari Browser on iOS 7 not showing an element's background-color through padding?

If I have the following markup:

```
<div style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px; padding: 10px;">
    Padded div
</div>
```

I see a 30px red square instead of a 50px red square ONLY on my iOS 7 (7.0.4) Safari browser.
Every other browser is giving my my 50px red square.

Comment: Hard to tell by just looking at this piece. Looks fine to me, except for the missing closing quotation " at the end. Also I'd suggest using CSS instead of in-line styles, especially for this much. Last thing I would check is if this happens on lower iOS browsers? Anyway I don't think iOS 7 Safari will render box model differently than other webkit browsers.

Comment: This is just sample code to demo the issue. Issue exists with inline styles as well as stylesheets. From [other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376129/padding-doesnt-seem-to-be-displaying-correctly-on-ios/20102867#20102867), it seems to be affecting background images as well. Unfortunately, I don't have easy access to previous iOS browsers to validate, but desktop Safari does render properly.

Comment: I don't have a device to test that for you at the moment but right off the top of my head I would suggest using media query to define a different style targeting only mobile safari.

Comment: What makes it worse it acts as a transparent area, so anything behind the padding shows through.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, too. funny enough, if i disable the padding in the console and reenable it again, the bg color works just fine.

Comment: my solution for now is so fugly, that i dont dare to submit it as an answer: i use javascript setTimeout to add a class, that includes the padding. i set it to 300ms, that seems just enought to make it work. uah.